How to Identify the Cause of Mobile Opt-Out in Data Views?
I'm working with Data Views and trying to analyze the causes of mobile opt-outs. In the _PushAddress data views, I noticed the presence of the field _OptOutMethodId, but there doesn't seem to be any accompanying documentation or data that explains what each ID value represents.
Does anyone know how to map _OptOutMethodId to specific opt-out reasons or methods? Is there a reference table or a way to decode these IDs?

No, it is not similar. There is no information what specific OptOutMethod means.

https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_as_data_view_sms_subscription_log.htm&type=5

@identigral The link you sent contains explanation for opt out method ids but for sms not for pushes. For example I see in all contacts that a customer has opt out source = 'User disabled push'. I don't see it in the ids for sms in the link you sent
